# What's my word?

Tags: word

The numbers `95 68 53 20` spell a "country name".

What country am I?

You don't need to separate the numbers

All of the numbers represent two letters, except 53, which is one letter.

I hope you're good at science.

Comment: If the hints are fundamental to the solution of the puzzle then they should be part of the puzzle and not left as hints.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  You might want to look around a little and see how other folks frame their puzzles. As @n_palum mentioned, vital hints shouldn't be "hints", they're part of the puzzle.  Non-vital hints are generally best left until some time has passed with no progress on the puzzle, rather than given right away, as they can give away far too much about the puzzle up front.  Thanks for joining the PSE community!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elementary, my dear Wheatley!

> Your "country name", really the common name of a pair of continents, is AMERICA. 95 = **Am**ericium, 68 = **Er**bium, 53 = **I**odine, 20 = **Ca**lcium

Comment: Well Done. My first puzzle was too easy, it seems... Better think of a new one quick!

Comment: You made it too easy with the "hints", especially where you called out 53 as being one letter.

Comment: @DavidWheatley As the correct answer seems to have been given, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 2):

You are

> America. Spelled using Periodic table letters.